# Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AnimatePresenceProps'.ts(2559)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

This error just started happening randomly:

[image]

However if I make a wrapping component that spreads props and introduces children there's no error:

```
const WorkingVersion = (props: {id?: number}) => <SimpleComponent {...props}><div>hello</div></SimpleComponent>
```

This issue also does not happen on codesandbox for typescript making me think it's a specific issue on my machine.

I tried reverting to the last working version however it somehow didn't fix the issue I was having.

What should I be looking for that could cause this error to popup?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a recent bug caused by [this PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56210) on types of react v18. Other people are having same problems where everything breaks down after the update, see [the recent issues opened here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues). My suggestion is to downgrade the react types until they release a hotfix for this. See also [this issue](https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/1509)

Comment: i ended up downgrading back to react 17 until all the modules I'm using get updated to be comp[atible.

Comment: This also worked for my project, downgraded to 17 and I was able to compile out. Wait until 18 gets its act together - thanks @Yago

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same issue today.

What worked for me is changing `node_modules\@types\react line:511` which is the interface definition of Function Component from

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: P, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
    displayName?: string | undefined;
}
```

to

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
    displayName?: string | undefined;
}
```

This is just a temporary fix to be able to work with framer-motion in the meantime. We'll probably have to wait till they release the bugfix PR.

Answer (score 6):

This workaround fixed it for me.

Create a `framer-motion.d.ts` file on the project root directory and add the following code snippet.

```js
import * as React from 'react';

declare module 'framer-motion' {
  export interface AnimatePresenceProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing this caused all kinds of other issues like `'"framer-motion"' has no exported member named 'AnimatePresence'. Did you mean 'AnimatePresenceProps'?` - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and fixed it by wrapping the props type declaration of my `SimpleComponent` in `PropsWithChildren<{...}>`

Something like this:

```js
function SimpleComponent(props: PropsWithChildren<{
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
  ...
}>) {
  return <div>...</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redeclare the component with same name for example if using `framer-motion`, and let VS Code use that component. Like below:

```
import {
     AnimatePresenceProps,
     AnimatePresence as _AnimatePresence
} from "framer-motion";

export const AnimatePresence = (
    p: AnimatePresenceProps & {
        children: React.ReactNode;
    }
) => {
    return <_AnimatePresence {...p} />;
};
```